# Change function in jQuery is firing twice on postback

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having an issue with the change function in jQuery 1.7.1 and postbacks. Basically I need to toggle the disabled attribute of buttons depending on whether an item is selected in the dropdown. In the code I have:

```
<input type="button" id="btnRed" value="show Red" disabled="disabled" class="spButton" />
<input type="button" id="btnBlue" value="show Blue"   disabled="disabled" class="spButton"/>
<input type="button" id="btnYellow" value="show Yellow" disabled="disabled"  class="spButton" />
```

I have my asp dropdown with autopostback set to true

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="selAccount" runat="server"  
    onselectedindexchanged="selAccount_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">select me</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="234">234</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and the jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selAccount").change(function () {
        var selValue = $(this).val();

        if (selValue == '-1') {
            $(".spButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        else {
            $(".spButton").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
 });
```

invariably, when postback occurs, the buttons remain disabled. I tested with an enabled button and it is firing twice. i have tried different approaches (bin, unbind) to no avail. I got around this issue with a hidden variable set on the SelectedIndexChanged in  code-behind and interrogating the hidden variable value in jQuery. is there an issue with the change method? is there a better way to do this? any insight would be appreciated. thanks,

Comment: I tested this issue in Firefox and I get the same results.

Comment: The code flickers once with the desired behavior and then it goes back to disabled after postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a postback each time the value is changed, then the page is reloaded and the changes made by jQuery are lost..

Either stop the auto-postback (*set it to `false`*), or if required change your code from the `change` event to the `ready` event..

```
$(function(){
    var selValue = $("#selAccount").val();

    if (selValue == '-1') {
        $(".spButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else {
        $(".spButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: @joseluisrod, you missed my point.. I am saying not to bind to the `change` event at all.. Just run the code (*the actual code that enables/disables the buttons*) inside the `ready` event.. If you notice my code, you will see that i have removed the `.change` part.. The solution is to disable auto-postback if possible. If not possible then use the code i posted..